# Unexpected regex behavior when executed in base R

Tags: r, regex

As per this [link](https://regex101.com/r/oGboCX/1), I wrote a regex that does not give the expected result when executed for a specific string in R:

```
string <- "0,9% BB"
regex  <- "^ ?\\d+[\\d ,\\.]*[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z\\/]*%?"   
grep(regex, string, value = T, perl = T)
```

The result output is

```
 [1] "0,9% BB"
```

instead of the desired (and outputed by the link)

```
[1] "0,9%"
```

What am I missing to get the desired output? Preferably base R, please.

Answer (score 1):

This returns "0,9%" using only base R

```
string <- "0,9% BB"
regex  <- "^ ?\\d+[\\d ,\\.]*[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z\\/]*%?"
regmatches(x = string, m = regexpr(regex,string,perl = TRUE))
```

Comment: Great, thank you. However, I really can´t figure out why it does not work when using grep () ...

Comment: I’m thinking grep() on its own returns the whole string if a match is found.

Comment: Sure! grep("a", "abc", value = T, perl = T) results "abc". Thanks again.